# c# and sqlite: how fix too many SQL variables?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I have Xamarin Forms app. This app use [sql-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). Sometimes i get an error:

```
[0:] SQLite.SQLiteException: too many SQL variables
```

I found that this is due to restrictions, and I need to change the parameter SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER.
This is function for change:

```
 [sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER,size)][1]
```

but how do I run this function with/in sql-net-pcl?

Comment: Your  sqlite may touch the Maximum Number Of Host Parameters In A Single SQL Statement mentions as follows https://sqlite.org/limits.html .

Comment: Yes, but I don't use "clear sqlite",  I use sql-net package. how do I run this function with/in sql-net-pcl?

Comment: @FetFrumos do you find a solution ?

Comment: @MarcOberlé no, I switched to another project. maybe the latest versions of the libraries fix it